# hadoop metrics2 example for PrometheusMetricsSink

Tags: hadoop, prometheus

Is there an example of setting up PrometheusMetricsSink with hadoopMetrics2 properties? The properties file that came with has only properties for FileSink, GraphiteSink and Ganglia, nothing on propermteusmetricssink.

All i want is to get hadoop metrics compatible with prometheus so that I can use prometheus scrape to display dashboard.
It will be great if I can use thes approach with other apache products like accumulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus isn't a sink; it polls from scrape targets.

You'd add the [JMX Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter) to the individual JVM components of Hadoop (Datanode, NameNode, ResourceManager, NodeManager, etc), then configure Prometheus `scrape_configs` to read from each of those.